# problems doing drawing in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I need to put this drawing in my report (it is a vector x split into two vectors - one parallel to the line T(p,alpha) above and the other one othogonal to the other vector)

And then make a dashed line which corresponds to a parallel displacement of T(p,alpha)

Could anyone please help me? :)

Thanks :)

[image]

Comment: OK, and what is your problem exactly? Could you provide an MWE?

Answer (score 4):

This is a draft if you want to learn tikz. You need to use pgf 3.0. You can avoid the use of tkz-euclide. It's only here for the right angles but you can find on the stackexchange some code  with only tikz. You can use some nodes to place some texts or labels (read some pages of the pgfmanual !

Code updated Correction of some mistakes in the shift components

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tkz-euclide} 
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path coordinate (a) at (6,2)
          coordinate (b) at (-2,8)
          coordinate (c) at (-1,7.25);
   \draw (a)    -> (b)
         (-6,0) -- (6,0)
         (0,-2) -- (0,10);
\path   (0,0) coordinate(O)  -- (-2,1.5)  coordinate(R)--([turn]-90:1cm) coordinate(S);
\path   (a)   -- (c)  --([turn]90:1cm) coordinate(c');
\begin{scope}[]
    \draw[->,arrows = {-Latex}] (O) -- (R) ;
    \draw[->,arrows = {-Latex}] (R) -- (S)
     node [above left] {%
                        $\begin{pmatrix}
                          \sin\alpha\\
                         -\cos\alpha
                         \end{pmatrix}$} ;
    \draw[->,arrows = {-Latex}] (O) -- (S) node[above=12pt,midway]{$x$} ;
    \draw[->,arrows = {-Latex}] (c) -- (c');    
 \end{scope}

  \draw[dashed] ([shift={(-0.6,-0.8)}]a) coordinate(a') -- ([shift={(-0.6,-0.8)}]b) coordinate(b');
    % thks percusse to simplify the code above shift instead of xshift etc.       
  \tkzMarkRightAngles[size=0.4](O,R,S c,c',a')  % thks wrtlprnft to see the mistake a instead of a'
  \node[above right] at (a){$T(P,\alpha)$}  ; 
  \node[below left] at (a'){$T(P,\alpha)-x$}    ;   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to begin with X and alpha ?
 I don't like the syntax to math with tikz `let \p1 ... \n1 ... in ...` It's perhaps shorter but I prefer the old style.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz} 

 \begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{-32}
    \coordinate (X) at (-1,1.25);
    \pgfmathparse{veclen(-1,1.25)} \pgfmathresult   \let\lX\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{\lX*cos(\angle)} \pgfmathresult   \let\r\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{\lX*sin(-\angle)} \pgfmathresult  \let\s\pgfmathresult
    \draw (0,0)  -- (X)
         (-2,0) -- (2,0)
         (0,-2) -- (0,2);
    \draw (X)--(0,0)--([turn]{180-\angle}:\r) coordinate(R)--([turn] -90:\s) coordinate(S);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Katrine No problem The only difficulties in the code are this =`([xshift={-0.75cm},yshift={-1cm}]a)` but you can find explanations on the pgfmanual. It's basic

Comment: You can use `([shift={(-0.75,-1)}]...)`

Comment: @percusse yes you are right but with tkz I forget how to use tikz ! :)

Comment: Out of curiosity: why is one of the right angle marks skewed a bit?

Comment: @wrtlprnft well seen I used a instead of a' !

Comment: @AlainMatthes - can you adjust the scales so that the shift of the line actually matches the short component of the vector ?

Comment: @Thruston like in my last update ? or perhaps  I did not understand your remark ...

Comment: Yes, I guess.  But I was sort of hoping to see how to calculate the vector components in TikZ.   I know how to do this in MP (see my answer), but I was curious to see a TikZ equivalent.

Comment: @Thruston  I made some mistakes in the shift ...

Comment: @Thruston I have a problem to understand the metapost code. If I understand, you begin with X and then calculate r and s with alpha ...that's it something like X cos(alpha) etc ... ?

Comment: @AlainMatthes I'll add a note of explanation to my answer

Comment: @Thruston ok it's possible to do the same thing with pff/tikz. We can multiply by a matrix

Answer (score 3):

And here's an attempt at a tutorial-type answer if you want to learn [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) with [`luamplib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib).  If you set the drawing out carefully you an get MP to do most of the arithmetic for you.  So here you can change `alpha` to change the rotation of the line or redefine the position of `X` and the rest of the diagram will adjust itself accordingly.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

% first define some paths for x axis, y axis 
path xx, yy;
xx = (left--right) scaled 144;
yy = (2 down -- 9 up) scaled 21;
draw xx withcolor .4 white;
draw yy withcolor .4 white;

% now the line, you can change the rotation by changing alpha
path tt;
alpha = -32;
tt = (left -- 2 right) scaled 50 rotated alpha shifted 160 up;

% the vector X
pair X;
X = (-42, 64);  % or whatever 

% and now find its components relative to the rotation of the line
pair r, s;
r = (xpart (X rotated -alpha), 0) rotated alpha;
s = (0, ypart (X rotated -alpha)) rotated alpha;

% draw the vector X and its components
draw r--X--s dashed withdots scaled 1/2 withcolor 1/2 white;
drawarrow origin -- r; 
drawarrow origin -- s;
drawarrow origin -- X withcolor .53 red; 

% finally the path shifted -s
path tt';
tt' = tt shifted -s;

% draw the paths
drawoptions(withcolor .673 blue);
draw tt;
draw tt' dashed evenly;
drawarrow point 0.1 of tt -- point 0.1 of tt';
drawoptions();

% add some labels
label.urt ("$\mathbf{X}$", 1/2 X);
label.lrt ("$\mathbf{s}$", 1/2 s);
label.llft("$\mathbf{r}$", 1/2 r);
label.ulft("$-\mathbf{s}$", 1/2[point 0.1 of tt, point 0.1 of tt']);

label.rt("$T(p,α)$",            point 1 of tt);
label.rt("$T(p,α)-\mathbf{X}$", point 1 of tt');

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

### Notes

- I've represented vectors here as `pair` variables, so I've defined `X` as a pair and set it to `(-42, 64)`
- The red arrow is a path from the origin to this point.
- To resolve a vector into its orthogonal components you can use `xpart` and `ypart`.  So `xpart X` is -42 in this example.
- To resolve a vector into components parallel to the line `T` which is rotated at angle `alpha` to the horizontal, I have rotated `X` by `-alpha` first, then extracted the `x` and `y` parts and then rotated the resulting orthogonal points back to the original frame of reference.
- The operation `rotated theta` applied to a pair is like doing a matrix multiplication with `sin theta` and `cos theta`, so

  ```
  (x,y) rotated theta == ( x*cos(theta)+y*sin(theta), x*-sin(theta)+y*cos(theta) )
  ```